# how to execute https:// url in iframe

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, iframe

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <iframe src="https://google.com" style="width:1000px;height:1000px"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and error in console i.e.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=YE1eU9jPItDqrQe8g4GwCg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Comment: No. The frame options header response states that you may only use `SAMEORIGIN` when requesting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `https`.

Look at the error message:

```
 because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

Google are explicitly telling your browser that only `google.com` is allowed to display the page in an iframe.

There is no way to override this behaviour. It is Google's page.

The closest you could come would be to copy the content to your own server and display it there. Beware of international copyright law.

Comment: if i remove https://google.com and put https://www.amazon.in/ then also same error

Comment: @MohitJain — That just means Amazon are giving the browser the same instruction. Only Amazon is allowed to put Amazon's pages in frames.